# Spring : Tomcat datasource via JNDI in my Spring configuration Problem?

Tags: spring, jndi

I want to read Tomcat datasource via JNDI in my Spring configuration i am using oracle toplink
in spring applicationContext.xml i am using like below

`<bean id="UserDatabase" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ISM_rep_user"></property>
<property name="lookupOn" value="true"></property></bean>`

and in tomcat/conf/context.xml i am using below

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `lookupOn` property has no vaid XML syntax (missing `"`)?